# Generated group of 2 element of order 2

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group that is generated by $\alpha,\beta\in{G}$ of order 2, such that their product isn't of order 2. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $D_n$ for some n.

Comment: What is your definition of $D_n$?

Comment: Perhaps lhf's question stems from the fact that in some cases finite dihedral groups are defined precisely that way: as groups generated by two non-commutative involutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\gamma = \alpha \cdot \beta$ and $n$ its order. Show that $G$ is generated by $\{\alpha, \gamma\}$. Then figure out that a relation between $\alpha $ and $\gamma $ is precisely the defining relation for the generators of the Dihedral group $D_n$.

Comment: Depending on how $D_n$ is defined, this is trivial: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Equivalent_definitions.

Comment: @lhf I assumed OP was given the definition (or at least had seen) of $D_n$ using generators and relations, and then, yes, it's quite straightforward.